# Pushing event handlers to parent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If, for example, I have a spreadsheet and want to attach handlers to cells to handle a users interaction. Typically, you would attach the handlers to the cell component itself. But if you are creating thousands of cells, this seems rather inefficient.

If I had a component hierarchy where SheetComponent -> CellComponents how can I attach a single handler to SheetComponent to handle each cell interaction? When the user interacts, I would like to have access to CellComponents props in order to identify which was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM events, when using React are synthetic ... they are all handled at the document level and then synthesized across all handlers. So, for DOM events, a handler hasn't been attached to each element for each event. However, that still means there is overhead that can't be avoided as your components would need to be notified that an event has occurred.

For communicating to the `SheetComponent` from a `CellComponent`, you could simply add your own event as a property: `onCellActivated` for example. If you have more than a couple, you could, instead of having lots of events needing to be wired up, you could have a generic event with an argument set to the type of event:

```
 onCellEvent({ eventType: 'activation', cell: this })
```

That pattern starts to look more like an Action Creator/Action following the Flux pattern (without the Dispatcher and Store of course).

Instead of relying on your own events, you could use a [Flux/Action/Dispatcher](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html) pattern potentially to relay key events to a centralized location (like the `SheetComponent`) and from there handle the interaction. With the action dispatched, you would include the key information about the cell where the interaction took place.

But, you might want to test the performance of a more traditional event model first as this might add extra complexity with little actual benefit.

You might also want to take some inspiration from [Facebook's Fixed Data Table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table) component, written for React. It's designed to handle thousands of rows of data efficiently.

Comment: If table cells are the deepest components in the hierarchy, it seems like a simple solution would be to just add a click handler to the spreadsheet parent that identifies the cell clicked by `event.target`, like [this](http://codepen.io/AdamStone/pen/GgxjvK). Do you see any problem with this approach? Or just passing a handler from the parent to the cells through props?

Comment: The example you pointed to is JQuery though? Using props is very typical React and a good place to start.

Comment: And one other thing...the amount of code that you'd need to write for any reasonable solution is quite small. So, I'd try something you're comfortable with that is easy to understand and debug, and see where that takes you.

Comment: JQuery just seemed like the simplest way to make an event handler example in codepen, but I had the impression that event handlers in React components behave the same way.

Comment: Ahh -- yes, events bubble and that's the way they work in React (with a reasonably different syntax) ... I just was surprised to see jQuery code. :)